# Stored procedure executed from dotnet including an execution plan

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures

is it possible to execute a stored procedure within dotnet framework/core with an existing execution plan,
so that is equals the execution plan in the sql server?

observing differences in calculation time when executing it in sql server or from dotnet

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what an execution plan is, it's not something you provide but rather something that is generated automatically and internally by SQL Server's Query Optimiser when you _run the query._  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/execution-plans?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: thanks, hoped I can use an existing execution plan generated from the sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the execution plan of a query rather than a stored procedure?

You can `analyze` the query on both environments, then try to create indexes or other conditions so that the two plans look similar to each other sometimes they are equivalent. You can affect the execution plan by creating indexes and in other ways (each sql dialect has its own ways), but you can't *set* it.